# Unit test fail with not being able to find global module

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, module, yaml

From the root of my project I am running the standard python unit-testing command.

```
python3 -m unittest
```

I end up with

```
doc = yaml.safe_load(f)
NameError: name 'yaml' is not defined
```

Here's a blueprint of the test code:

```
import unittest
import yaml
from validators.utils import get_settings_key
# from validators.validators import validate_assumed_role


class TestValidators(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        with open("boilerplate_aws.yaml") as f:
            self.doc = yaml.safe_load(f)
            self.infrastructure = self.doc["parameters"]["infrastructure"]
            self.inventory_role = self.infrastructure["assumed_role_arn"]
 
    def test_role_validator(self):
        settings_role = get_settings_key("assumed_role_arn")
        # self.assertTrue(validate_assumed_role(self.inventory_role, settings_role))
# 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I  consider the yaml module as a global one coming by default in Python. Just wondering if I am missing something or it's some project messed up structure ? Just for safety check, I looked up the package and it's here locally. This is under Ubuntu. No venvs, or anything like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo python -m pip install pyyaml
```

If that doesn't work try installing a specific version like this:

```
pip install pyyaml==X.XX
```

These possible solutions were found on this github [issue](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/291).